# Is there a way to synchronously read the contents of HTTP request body in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, post

So I am sending an HTTP POST request to a node.js HTTP server that's running locally. I wish to extract the JSON object from the HTTP body, and use the data it holds to do some stuff on the server side.

Here is my client app, which issues the request:

```
var requester = require('request');

requester.post(
        'http://localhost:1337/',
        {body:JSON.stringify({"someElement":"someValue"})}, 
        function(error, response, body){
                if(!error)
                {
                        console.log(body);
                }
                else
                {
                        console.log(error+response+body);
                        console.log(body);
                }
        }
);
```

Here's the server that is supposed to receive that request:

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    var chunk = {};
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {                   
        chunk = JSON.parse(chunk);
    });

    if(chunk.someElement)
    {
            console.log(chunk);
            // do some stuff
    }
    else
    {
        // report error
    }

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Done with work \n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Now the issue is, since the `req.on()` function that has a callback extracts the POST data asynchronously, it seems like `if(chunk.someElement)` clause is evaluated before that is done, and so it always goes to the else clause and I am unable to do anything at all.

- Is there a simpler way to handle this issue (by simpler, I mean: not
  using any other fancy libraries or modules, just pure node)?
- Is there
  a synchronous function that performs the same tasks as `req.on()` and
  returns the contents of the body before I do the
  `if(chunk.someElement)` check?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15470157/269061

Comment: Have a look on my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49537568/453767) where I have compared sync and async ways of reading request data.

Comment: You shouldn't code anything in Node.js with syncronous logic. Async code is sometimes slightly harder to write but that's the way to go with Node.js. You can use `async` and Promises to hide the async code a bit if you want.

Answer (score 5):

You need to wait and buffer the request and parse/use the JSON on the request's 'end' event instead because there is no guarantee that all data will be received as a single chunk:

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    var buffer = '';
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
      buffer += chunk;
    }).on('end', function() {
      var result;
      try {
        result = JSON.parse(buffer);
      } catch (ex) {
        res.writeHead(400);
        return res.end('Bad JSON');
      }

      if (result && result.someElement)
      {
        console.log(chunk);
        // do some stuff
      }
      else
      {
        // report error
      }

      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      res.end('Done with work \n');
    }).setEncoding('utf8');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```