# Async/Await degrades server performance

Tags: node.js, http, async-await

I'm using the following code to write a HTTP server to check if using `async/await` can impact the performance

```
const http = require('http')

const server = http.createServer(reqResHandler);

server.listen(3000, err => {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log('Server listening on: http://localost:3000')
})
```

**Without Promise**

```
const reqResHandler = (req, res) => {
    req.body = [];
    req.on('data', (chunk)=>req.body.push(chunk));
    req.on('end', ()=>{
      req.body = Buffer.concat(req.body);
      res.setHeader("content-length", req.body.length);
      res.end(req.body);
    });

};
```

**With Promise**

```
async function getBody(req){
    var end = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      req.on('data', (chunk)=>req.body.push(chunk));
      req.on('end', ()=>{req.body = Buffer.concat(req.body); resolve(req.body)});
      req.on('error', reject); // or something like that
  });

  await end;

  return req.body;
}


const reqResHandler = async (req, res) => {
    req.body = [];
    var data = await getBody(req);
    res.setHeader("content-length", data.length);
    res.end(data);
};
```

When I use the code without promise it gives throughput up to 30-31k requests per second. But if I use code with promise then it gives performance up to 27-27.5k rps max.

Am I using the async await incorrectly?

Comment: i think that's expected. that's performance hit from async/await

Comment: you don't need to introduce one extra layer of async/await - `getBody` can return the `Promise` directly. Since this promise is resolved with the request data, you get it into the `data` variable in `reqResHandler`...

Comment: I tried that way. But it didn't work.

Comment: my bad I forgot to write the return statement. Though no improvement in performance

Comment: Async-await doesn't bring the magic bullet into your code. It simply provide an opportunity to **accept** more requests per second, not to handle them - the resources of system are limited, and async-await provides additional overhead to creating the structs for awaiting the results.

Answer (score -1):

You can do the async like this:

```
async function getBody(req){
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  req.on('data', (chunk)=>req.body.push(chunk));
  req.on('end', ()=>{req.body = Buffer.concat(req.body); resolve(req.body)});
  req.on('error', reject); // or something like that
});
}


 const reqResHandler = async (req, res) => {
req.body = [];
let data = (await getBody(req)).body;
res.setHeader("content-length", data.length);
res.end(data);
```

};